# How to make StreamBuilder scroll working inside a ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project, I have one **SteamBuilder** wrapped by a Container which is inside a **ListView** and the body part of Scaffold is a Column.

It looks like below image-

[image]

in the image, the blue part is Container 1 , the yellow section is the Stream builder one(inside that I load some data from API), the red section is Container 2.

**Now the problem is ------**

When I scroll through the Container 1 and Container 2 the scroll works perfectly, but when I scroll through the **StreamBuilder** Container it doesn't work.

**Here's my code-**

```
    return Scaffold(

      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[


                  Container(

                    width: double.minPositive,
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.blue,

                    child: Text("Container 1"),
                  ),


                Container(

                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 300,

                  child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: bloc.allFrontList,
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ModelFrontList>> snapshot){
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return buildList(snapshot);
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                        }
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

                      }
                  ),
                ),


                Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.red,

                  child: Text("Container 2"),
                ),

              ],

            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 60,
            width: double.maxFinite,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(

                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[

                showBottomIcons(Icons.home, "Home", "/HomeScreen"),
                showBottomIcons(Icons.category, "Category", "/CategoryScreen"),
                showBottomIcons(Icons.shopping_cart, "Cart", "/CartScreen"),
                showBottomIcons(Icons.person, "Account", "/AccountScreen"),

              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget buildList(AsyncSnapshot<List<ModelFrontList>> snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(

      shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(

              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 20),
              child: Text("${snapshot.data[index].products[index].nameEnglish}"),
              //onTap: () => openDetailPage(snapshot.data, index),
          );
        });
  }
```

So, I need a solution to make the entire screen scrollable in every container including the mentioned StreamBuilder.

Answer (score 8):

The issue here is that you're returning another list in your StreamBuilder and your dragging gesture is passed through to that list (which contains the elements in the yellow container). 
It's not entirely clear what the full desired functionality is, but a quick fix is to add

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

To your ListView.Builder.

A better solution (depending on your desired functionality) would be to not use a scrollable widget to display the data from your StreamBuilder, and make sure the parent container adjusts it's height according to the number of elements you load.

If you want to keep scrolling functionality for the loaded elements as well, you will have to attach controllers to both lists and once the inner list reaches the end, forward the scroll offset to the outer controller.

Comment: You just saved me a whole lotta headache with this. Thank you so much

Comment: this is amazing<3